# Has anybody implement authorization with loopback4?

Tags: loopback4

I'm trying to implement an authorization system into our business application with loopback 4 and casbin, I implemented it successfully using https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-auth-access-control-example.html#migrating-example-to-loopback-4-with-casbin this article but it does not fit our business locaion, is there any other I can implement ACL simpler than casbin?

Comment: Check this out. This package we use in many LB4 applications. It has casbin support as well as non-casbin based authorization as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback4-authorization

Comment: did you want to implement JWT auth

Answer (score 1):

This package provides many different ways to implement authorization in loopback-next applications. https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback4-authorization

A very basic usage is mentioned below. But many more mechanisms are also available.

```
npm install loopback4-authorization
```

- Add component to application.

```
this.bind(AuthorizationBindings.CONFIG).to({
  allowAlwaysPaths: ['/explorer'],
});
this.component(AuthorizationComponent);
```

- Implement Permissions interface in User model and add permissions array.

```
@model({
  name: 'users',
})
export class User extends Entity implements Permissions<string> {
  // .....
  // other attributes here
  // .....

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
  })
  permissions: string[];

  constructor(data?: Partial<User>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

- Add a step in custom sequence to check for authorization whenever any end
  point is hit.

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {
  FindRoute,
  HttpErrors,
  InvokeMethod,
  ParseParams,
  Reject,
  RequestContext,
  RestBindings,
  Send,
  SequenceHandler,
} from '@loopback/rest';
import {AuthenticateFn, AuthenticationBindings} from 'loopback4-authentication';
import {
  AuthorizationBindings,
  AuthorizeErrorKeys,
  AuthorizeFn,
} from 'loopback4-authorization';

import {AuthClient} from './models/auth-client.model';
import {User} from './models/user.model';

const SequenceActions = RestBindings.SequenceActions;

export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
  constructor(
    @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
    @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
    @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
    @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
    @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
    @inject(AuthenticationBindings.USER_AUTH_ACTION)
    protected authenticateRequest: AuthenticateFn<AuthUser>,
    @inject(AuthorizationBindings.AUTHORIZE_ACTION)
    protected checkAuthorisation: AuthorizeFn,
  ) {}

  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    const requestTime = Date.now();
    try {
      const {request, response} = context;
      const finished = await this.invokeMiddleware(context);
      if (finished) return;
      const route = this.findRoute(request);
      const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);

      const authUser: User = await this.authenticateRequest(
        request,
        response,
      );
      // This is the important line added for authorization. 
      const isAccessAllowed: boolean = await this.checkAuthorisation(
        authUser?.permissions,
        request,
      );
      // Checking access to route here
      if (!isAccessAllowed) {
        throw new HttpErrors.Forbidden(AuthorizeErrorKeys.NotAllowedAccess);
      }

      const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
      this.send(response, result);
    } catch (err) {
      this.reject(context, err);
    }
  }
}
```

The above sequence also contains user authentication using [loopback4-authentication](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-authentication) package. You can refer to the documentation for the same for more details.

- Now we can add access permission keys to the controller methods using authorize
  decorator as below.

```
@authorize(['CreateRole'])
@post(rolesPath, {
  responses: {
    [STATUS_CODE.OK]: {
      description: 'Role model instance',
      content: {
        [CONTENT_TYPE.JSON]: {schema: {'x-ts-type': Role}},
      },
    },
  },
})
async create(@requestBody() role: Role): Promise<Role> {
  return await this.roleRepository.create(role);
}
```

This endpoint will only be accessible if logged in user has permission
'CreateRole'.

For a quick starter guide, you can refer to the [loopback 4 starter application](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-starter) which contains authorization in a multi-tenant system.

Comment: This is already in the documentation, and you did not even properly copy it.

Comment: Yeah. I intended to give you more and only relevant context. Ultimately that extension is the one that you can use. I hope that helps.